# How to get alpha value of a hexadecimal color in R

Tags: r, colors, alpha-transparency

I would like to get alpha value of colors in a vector. However, I could not find any function for this.

However, I can parse the last part of the hexadecimal representation:

```
transparent.colors = alpha(c("red", "black"), alpha = 0.5)
transparency = substr(transparent.colors, start = 8, stop = 9)
strtoi(paste0("0x", transparency)) / 255
```

I think there should be some function implemented already. Any search often leads to irrelevant results (e.g. adding transparency to  plots).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R doesn't have a built in `alpha()` function, so I'm going to assume you're using [this `alpha()` function from the "scales" package.](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/scales/versions/0.4.1/topics/alpha)

The best answer I could find was to use the built-in [col2rgb() function.](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/col2rgb.html) Try something like this:

```
transparent.colors = alpha(c("red", "black"), alpha = 0.5)
col2rgb(transparent.colors)[4] / 255
col2rgb(transparent.colors, alpha=TRUE)["alpha",] # You can use the row name if you prefer.
```

Comment: I was using alpha from ggplot2, but I missed alpha parameter of col2rgb. Thanks.